# Web-based Dropbox and Google Docs integration

Tags: google-workspace, google-drive, synchronization, dropbox, office-online

At my workplace people heavily use **web apps** for productivity, Dropbox is used as a backup solution, and Google Docs (custom **Google Apps domain**) is used for ocassional documents that need to be edited by many at once.

Most of the files consist of MS Office and OpenOffice files, so I was wondering if Dropbox and GDocs could be sync'ed so every ***office** file could be edited with any suite.

There are some desktop-based solutions for Windows (**syncplicity.com**) and OSX (**insynchq.com**), but I was wondering if there was a **web-based solution** that automatically handle this. I am considering **[developing it by myself](http://gist.github.com/600457)**, but it's rather complicated. Any ideas?

Comment: Votebox: https://www.dropbox.com/votebox/130/google-docs-integration

Comment: More discussion: http://getsatisfaction.com/dropbox/topics/sync_dropbox_with_google_docs

Comment: Other Super User thread: http://superuser.com/questions/65893/sync-google-docs-with-dropbox-automatically

Comment: What's wrong with the answer to the SuperUser question?

Comment: @Simon Brown: As I said, I would like a Web-Application, not another desktop client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try cloudHQ for Dropbox: http://cloudHQ.net/dropbox This service synchronizes Dropbox with Google Docs. Also there is a Google Chrome extension which enables you to manage (copy, move, etc.) and even edit Dropbox files directly from a Google Docs interface: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/iobcbdgacfkninlcbphihhdlkobkehia

Answer (score 1):

If the files are MS Office, then the new docs.com site should work - it's like Google Docs, but using MS applications online. If you're using Office Live then you can also save / open direct from the 'cloud'.

Comment: Good tip, but I would like to stick with GDocs, as I'm using Google Apps with custom domain, also I prefer it, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would have to setup a custom solution for this, involving a script that periodically pulls the latest version from gdocs and puts it in your dropbox folder and vice versa. I think, however, that you would have a problem going both direction due to perpetually differences in code formatting. You would really want to set this up one way or the other, probably so that dropbox is strictly a backup/archive solution and the documents are edited in google docs.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, maybe only Dropbox developers can achieve this in a clean way.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Google is releasing a similar service as a desktop app: http://googleenterprise.blogspot.com/2010/11/bridge-to-cloud-google-cloud-connect.html

Answer (score 0):

A service called Cloudseed has emerged to solve this issue, currently in closed beta: http://cloudseed.me/

Comment: This service closed

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a Mac?

By far the simplest way is to install both Dropbox and Google Drive clients on your laptop and create a symlink from Dropbox to your Google Drive folder. Essentially, your GDrive becomes just another "folder" inside Dropbox, which stays in sync whenever you create/edit/delete any Google Drive doc.